# structs and typedef in C

Tags: c

If I created a structure:

```
struct student {
int id;
char name [20];
student * next};
```

What is the meaning of:

```
typedef struct student student?
```

What does `student * next`?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered reading an [introductory book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?

Answer (score 3):

A `typedef` creates a new name. Thus these are completely equivalent:

```
student *next;
struct student *next;
```

In your example the struct and the typedef have the same name. But it could be like this:

```
struct something {
/* ... */
};

typedef struct something student;
```

The declaration of a typedef looks like the type it introduces.

---

As a side side note, [things are different in C++](http://c-faq.com/struct/impltypedef.html).

Comment: And you can short cut doing `typedef struct something { ... } something;`

Comment: @Eregrith: Or even `typedef struct { ... } something;`

Comment: The shortcut does not work, however, when you want the struct to contain pointers to itself. In this case, if you want to use the typedef name inside the struct definition, you need to first typedef the incomplete struct type before defining the struct.

Answer (score 1):

`typedef struct student student;`

This create an alias for `struct student` with the name `student`.

Structure tags and type names live in two different namespaces in C (not true in C++), so it is allowed to use the same name for the alias and for the tag.

Answer (score 0):

In C, whenever using structs you have to use the keyword `struct`. By typedefing `typedef struct student student`, you're able to say `struct student` by simply saying `student`.

Answer (score 0):

With a named structure, the keyword `struct` most usually be used to create instances of the structure and to reference the structure type at all.

The `typedef` allows you to virtually create an alias for `student` instead of having to use `struct student` constantly, thereby actually making it behave more like a built-in type.